# Conversion of Numeric to Date and Matching with other Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I am facing issue to convert `Date` of the Data Frame to Date Format. I have also tried using this `DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%Y%M")` but got an error. Can anyone help me in solving this.

```
DF
        Date    Price   Stock       
    1   201102  339.32  AAPL
    2   201103  353.21  AAPL
    3   201104  348.45  AAPL
    4   201105  348.23  AAPL
    5   201106  347.83  AAPL
    6   201107  335.67  AAPL
    7   201108  390.48  AAPL
    8   201109  384.83  AAPL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zoo::as.yearmon`:

```
library(zoo);
df %>%
    mutate(Date = as.yearmon(as.character(Date), "%Y%m"))
#      Date  Price Stock
#1 Feb 2011 339.32  AAPL
#2 Mar 2011 353.21  AAPL
#3 Apr 2011 348.45  AAPL
#4 May 2011 348.23  AAPL
#5 Jun 2011 347.83  AAPL
#6 Jul 2011 335.67  AAPL
#7 Aug 2011 390.48  AAPL
#8 Sep 2011 384.83  AAPL
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "        Date    Price   Stock
    1   201102  339.32  AAPL
    2   201103  353.21  AAPL
    3   201104  348.45  AAPL
    4   201105  348.23  AAPL
    5   201106  347.83  AAPL
    6   201107  335.67  AAPL
    7   201108  390.48  AAPL
    8   201109  384.83  AAPL", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

If each date corresponds to the first of the particular month you can use:

```
DF$Date <- lubridate::ymd(paste0(DF$Date, "01"))
```